# MySQL query help

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with the following structure:

**Table_1**

```
No  Name
1   Test1
2   Test2
2   Test3
```

**Table_2**

```
t_no  t_name  no
1     tname1  1
2     tname2  2
```

How can I write a query to get the result below

```
t_no  t_name  Name
1     tname1  Test1
2     tname2  Test3
```

In `Table1` two records have the same `id` but different values (i.e the difficulty).

Comment: How do you decide you want test3 instead of test2? From a relational point of view, they are equal. You should have a column in table1 that differs for these two values (NO_ORDER or something)

Comment: Is the third row in Table 1 an error? Should it be `3 Test3` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tables are named `table_1` and `table_2`

```
SELECT 
  table_2.t_no,
  table_2.t_name, 
  table_1.Name
FROM table_1 JOIN table_2 ON table_1.no = table_2.t_no
```

Or another method:

```
SELECT 
  table_2.t_no,
  table_2.t_name, 
  table_1.Name
FROM table_1, table_2
WHERE table_1.no = table_2.t_no
```

Comment: table 1 is having 2 records for dame value so how can we get Test3

Comment: With this table structure, you cannot get Test3.  You have to have an identity (primary key) column in Table 1 that directly relates to Table 2 in a 1:1.  Otherwise, you will always get both values where `No = 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  grpt1.t_no,
  grpt1.t_name, 
  table_2.Name
FROM table_2
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT t_no
           , MAX(t_name)
      FROM table_1
      GROUP BY t_no
    ) AS grpt1
    ON table_2.no = grpt1.t_no
```